# document.getElementById for a recently generated element

Tags: javascript, html, web, game-engine, game-development

Sorry I have read the previous threads regarding this topic but it is still not working in my case!

Some context is this is a for a simple javascript game. When the user mouses over an inventory item I want it to reveal a short description of the item.

23/06/2021 EDIT - okay heres a cut down version
Relevant code:

```
**HTML**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script defer src="scaled.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scaled.css">


    <title>Scaled</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<div id= "inventory" class = "inventory" ></div>

<div id= "itemtext" class = "itemtext" >A test item!</div>

<button id = "button" onclick = "addImage()">test</button> 

   
</body>
</html>




 **CSS**

.itemtext{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 80px;
    top:50px;
    color: red;  
    z-index: 200;
   
}

.itemtext-on{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: initial;
    color: green; 
    font-size: 80px;
    top:50px;
    z-index: 200;
   
}

#button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    color: blue;
}

**Javascript**
const itemText = document.getElementById('itemtext');
const inventory = document.getElementById('inventory');


function reveal() {
    itemText.classList.toggle('itemtext-on');
 }

 
 document.getElementById("Div1").onmouseover =  function()  {reveal()};
 

function addImage(){ 

var a = document.createElement("div");
 a.id = "Div1"; 
 var iconUrl = document.createElement("img");
 iconUrl.src = "bla.jpg";
 a.appendChild(itemText);
 a.appendChild(iconUrl);
 inventory.appendChild(a);
}
```

Error message is:
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmouseover' of null
at scaled.js:10"

So it does not like the fact I am trying to document.getElementById for a div which does not yet exist.

Appreciate any / all help :)

Comment: also `"it crashes"` doesn't help much to show us what really happens, can you show the error message? or provide a [mcve], please?

Comment: What is `itemText`?

Comment: What does the error say? Try to start there. Make sure that you are adding the event listener after div1 has been added to the DOM.

Comment: Are you sure you're creating the new element? The `if` test doesn't seem to be related to the element you're looking for.

Comment: Wow didn't expect to get responses so fast! Thank you guys.

itemText is just a HTML <P> with the item description - its added to the inventory image so it can be revealed on mouse over.

The error message im getting is: 

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onmouseover' of null at game3.js:214"

But its fine when i replace Div1 with an element which exists in the HTML from the start.

I read somewhere to move the Javascript src to the bottom of the HTML as it might be loading the Javascript file before the HTML file but that had no effect.

Comment: I will try breaking the problem down as Calvin suggested and then post it back up here (Thanks Calvin).

Comment: Barmar - basically the items are first added to the inventory as a text string and then converted into the corresponding item image - the text string is then hidden (but all that works just fine).

Comment: @HenryPucknell I suggest to [edit] your question to add all those relevant information. And don't be surprise, StackOverflow is really fast to get answers, but you need to help people to understand your problem to us be able to help you better. Take a look about [mcve]

Comment: I have edited my code above to make it a minimal reproducible example. I'm starting to think that I could just make Div1 exist from the outset but have it be completely hidden. Then when the inventory item is added it could be revealed! :D